# Naming a binary relation

Tags: relations

I have a non-symmetric binary relation `R` over a set `X` from which I derive the symmetric relation
$$
    R'(x,y) : \Leftrightarrow R(x,y) \text{ or } R(y,x)
$$
Is there a common name for this construction?

Comment: I was always fond of the name "Yord".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you point me to a previous use of your suggestion? I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: I don't know if there was any. But naming binary relations is kind of like naming kids. Only you get to name them with weird words, without scarring them for life.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, since there are [names for other operations on binary relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Operations_on_binary_relations), like reflexive closure or transitive closure, I was wondering whether the construction defined above has a similar common name. In that case, using that name would certainly help to communicate my ideas.

Comment: Symmetric closure, obviously.

Comment: @AsafKaragila . Have you seen the essay, by Carl Sagan,  "A Planet Named George"...?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Nope.

Comment: @AsafKaragila . William Hershel discovered Uranus. He claimed that as  he was the discoverer, he had the right to name it. He called it George after his patron, the king of England.  Naturally the French  would have none of this.